Error authenticating and signing in with Google in my React-Native application
LogIn.js:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';


function LogIn({ navigation }) {
    WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();
    const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState();
    const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState();
    const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
        androidClientId: '517261549891-ufcsui5d672mqsnvk239pq0q9oqmqqsl.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        expoClientId: '517261549891-6tl9b5ocrsot6kakm1fkmu70m31d93mq.apps.googleusercontent.com'

    });

    useEffect ( () => {
        if (response?.type == 'success')
        {
            setAccessToken(response.authentication.accessToken);
            console.log(response.authentication.accessToken);
            getUserData();
        }
    }, [response] )

    const getUserData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me",
                {
                    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
                }
            );
            const user = await response.json();
            console.log(user);
            setUserInfo(user);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching user data: ', error);
            Alert.alert('Error', 'Failed to fetch user data. Please try again later.');
        }
    };
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.bg}>
            <Text style={styles.heading}>Sign In/Up</Text>
            <Text style={styles.maintext}>Use advanced AI to learn more effectively than ever before, all for free.</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.googleSignInButton} onPress={() => promptAsync()}>
                <Ionicons name="logo-google" size={24} color="white" style={{marginRight: 10}} />
                <Text style={styles.googleSignInButtonText}>Sign in with Google</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.backButton}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('WelcomeScreen')}
            >
                <Text style={styles.backButtonText}>BACK</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    bg: {
        backgroundColor: '#020132',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
    },
    heading: {
        fontSize: 40,
        left: 20,
        top: 70,
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    maintext: {
        color: 'white',
        top: 85,
        left: 20,
        fontSize: 20,
    },
    googleSignInButton: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        left: 20,
        top: 150,
        backgroundColor: '#4285F4',
        width: 200,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        paddingTop: 12,
        paddingBottom: 12,
        paddingLeft: 12,
        paddingRight: 12,
    },
    googleSignInButtonText: {
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: 'medium',
        fontSize: 16,
    },
    backButton: {
        width: 130,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        top: 170,
        left: 20,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        paddingVertical: 10,
    },
    backButtonText: {
        color: '#0C0634',
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
    }
})

export default LogIn;

When I enter my React-Native application and try to authenticate on Google via LogIn.js (specifically the 'googleSignInButton'), my app crashes when Google is opened to authenticate from there.
My main objective is that:

the user authenticates with Google smoothly with no errors
the user returns to the LogIn.js screen

